# Find $\max_f | f'(a)|$ where $f$ ranges over a class of functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $\max_f \left|f'(a)\right|$ where $f$ ranges over the class of analytic functions bounded by $1$ in the unit disc, and $a$ is a fixed point of $|z|<1$. 
Show that $\displaystyle f'(a) = \lim_{z \to a} \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \ll \lim_{x \to a} \frac{B_a(x)}{z-a} = B_a'(a)$

By the hint, to assume that $f(a)=0$. Why the assume is okay?

And why $|f(z)| \leqslant \left|B_a(z)\right|$ for all $\left|z\right| \leqslant 1$?

Did I mis-understand that $B_a(z)$ means a open ball central at $z$ with radius $a$ ?
Thank you for @Philippe Malot

Sorry for the question and thank you.

Comment: An open ball? Really? What would be the meaning of $B'_a(a)$? I think that $B_a\colon z\mapsto\dfrac{|a|}{a}\dfrac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$.

Comment: @PhilippeMalot, would you mind show that $ |f(z)| \le |B_a(z)|$ for all $|z| \le 1$ ?